# Why PyQt5 import show a error about windows and bluetooth?

Tags: python, pyqt5

The import of PyQt5 come with this error:

```
C:\Python364>python.exe
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5.Qt import *
```

[image: error PyQt5, windows, bluetooth]

If I used the normal import of python module PyQt5, this error doesn't show:

```
C:\Python364>python.exe
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
>>> from PyQt5 import *
>>>
```

The question addresses several issues related to:

- Python integrity;
- the integrity of the PyQt5 mode;
- the integrity of the Windows 8.1 operating system;

Is that normal to happen?

Comment: I think that with the first command you are initializing some part of the [Qt Bluetooth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html) module, and in that initialization some drivers are being verified generating that alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtbluetooth-index.html

The Bluetooth API implemented into PyQt5 does not support Windows (yet?).

Importing PyQt5.Qt also imports the Bluetooth API of Qt - either downgrade to 5.9 (dont know at what point exactly this happens, but 5.9 and lower should be prior to the implementation) or specify your import.

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem. Also currently qt 5.9 no more available in PIP.

In my case just renamed file `C:\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin\Qt5Bluetooth.dll` to `_Qt5Bluetooth.dll`

No bluetooth dll, no problem :)

Answer (score -4):

Python 3. First of all, make sure that Python 3 is available on your system.

Install Xcode and command-line tools. If you are using OS X, download Xcode and install it. 
Install Qt Libraries.
Create a virtualenv for the PyQt5 and SIP libs.
Install SIP. 
Install PyQt5. 
All Done!